# How to Unmount all usb pen drive from ubuntu with bash script or terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to unmount all pen drive from ubuntu os through a bash script or from a terminal. I knew the command umount /media/MEDIA_NAME, but here we need to specify each MEDIA_NAME. Can I use a single command to unmount from terminal or bash script. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsing entries in /dev/disk/by-id/ allows you to select USB disks:

```bsh
for usb_dev in /dev/disk/by-id/usb-*; do
    dev=$(readlink -f $usb_dev)
    grep -q ^$dev /proc/mounts && umount $dev
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop for each device in the /media directory.

```
for device in /media/*
do
    umount $device
done
```

Comment: Im using ubuntu, here the keyword is umount

Comment: This will unmount everything, not just pen drives! Otherwise, just `umount /media/*` is enough to unmount everything in `/media`.